# TypeError: unorderable types: int() > Square()

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

```
class Square:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.size = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0}' .format(self.size)
    def bigger_than(self, t):
        if self.size > t:
            return True
        else:
            return False
s = Square(8)
t = Square(7)
if s.bigger_than(t):
    print('The first square is bigger than the second one.')
else:
    print('The first square is not bigger than the second one.')
```

The error message from this is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sourceFile", line 38, in <module>
    if s.bigger_than(t):
  File "sourceFile", line 14, in bigger_than
    if self.size > t:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > Square()
```

I think the problem is somewhere in `bigger_than` but I am not too sure. What I am trying to do is add a method that compares the size of the square with the size of another square and output whether the square is bigger or smaller.

if I try and `print()`, `self.size` and `t` it outputs the values from: `s = Square(8)` and `t = Square(7)`.

Comment: `if self.size > t.size:`

Comment: Also, you should implement it as `__gt__` not `bigger_than`, so you can use more natural syntax (`if s > t:`). See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: there is no error, this code is working fine for me.

Comment: @GaneshKamath presumably you're using Python 2.x, this error occurs only in 3.x. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: @GaneshKamath: yes, no exception in python `2.X` but output is always `The first square is bigger than the second one.` for any `size` value for object `t`

Answer (score 2):

You should implement as follows:

```
class Square:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.size = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Square({0.size})'.format(self)

    def __gt__(self, other):
       return self.size > other.size


s = Square(8)
t = Square(7)

if s > t:
    print('The first square is bigger than the second one.')
else:
    print('The first square is not bigger than the second one.')
```

Note that naming the method `__gt__` allows direct use of `>` (**g**reater **t**han), and we are explicitly comparing the `size` attributes of the two arguments (`s > t` is equivalent to `s.__gt__(t)` or `Square.__gt__(s, t)`).

I have also altered the `__repr__` to:

> look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)

You should read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for more information on these "magic methods".

Comment: I'd throw in a `@functools.total_ordering` decorator on the class.

Comment: @Kevin that is mentioned in the docs. It doesn't play nice with `NotImplemented`, which I also didn't cover, until 3.4 anyway.